# Rudin $9.3(a)$'s led me to a question about the existence logic quantifier and it's variables

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, quantifiers, linear-independence

> If $X$ is a vector space with $\dim X =n $, and $E=(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is a set of $n$ vectors, $E$ spans $X$ if and only if $E$ is independent.

This is theorem $9.3 (a)$ from Rudin, Principles of Mathematical Analysis. I don't understand the beginning of the proof.

Rudin starts with this observation: since $\dim X =n $, we have that: $\forall y\in X, (x_1, ...,x_n, y)$ is dependent.

This observation didn't seem obvious to me, so I tried to prove it by contradiction:

Suppose $\exists y\in X $ such that $ (x_1,...,x_n, y )$ is independent. Then, as the set $ (x_1,...,x_n, y )$ is included in $X$, we would have that $\dim X \ge n+1$. Contradiction.

However, this little reasoning has led me to another thought: is $$\exists y \in X , (x_1,...,x_n, y ) \text{ independent} \tag{1}$$

equivalent to $$ \exists (x_1, ...,x_{n+1}) \text{ independent} \tag{2}$$

?

There is one way (the one that I used in my short proof above) that seems rather obvious (if $(x_1,...,x_n)$ are fixed and we append $y$ at the end then we have the existence of $(x_1, ...,x_{n+1})$).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of dimension?

Comment: Dimension of a space is $\ge$ than $n$ if there exists a set of $n$ independent vectors that is included in the space. Dimension $\le$ than $n$ is similarly defined (taking the negation of the previous definition).

Comment: $(1)$ implies $(2)$ but $(2)$ does not imply $(1)$. In $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, $(2)$ is true, but $(1)$ holds only for *some* $(x_1,\dots,x_n),$ not all.

Comment: Since $\dim X =n $, by definition this means there does not exist $n+1$ vectors which are independent. In particular, $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, y)$ are $n+1$ vectors, and therefore $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n, y)$ is not independent.